# React / Redux how split input values with comma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm trying to split my input values with comma at onBlur function and set them to redux state as array but it's not working.

I read it at some topics that possible with **.split(',')**

my approach:

```
input onBlur={event = () => this.props.getValue(event.target.value)}
```

my action:

```
export const getValue = (value) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_VALUE',
      payload: value.split(',')
    });
  };
};
```

my reducer:

```
let initialState = {
  codes: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VALUE:
      return { ...state, codes: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

what i want at the end? :

i want in my reducer like that data:

```
codes: [28282, 28922, 18171, 27272, ....]
```

but it give me now something like that:

```
codes: [28282 28922 18171 27272 ....]
```

Comment: is it giving you a long string instead of an array ? like  `["28282 28922 18171 27272"]` ?

Comment: yes it's giving to me it

Comment: and the values you are entering are space-separated, not comma-separated?

Comment: then just do split(' ')

Comment: yes i press to space myself

Comment: so its not comma separated?

Comment: Then you have to split on the space, not comma: `payload: value.split(' ')`

Comment: But I think that would give you comma separated strings in array form.

Comment: yes it's give it to me : ["28282, 28922, 18171, 27272"]

Comment: `payload: value.split(' ').map(Number)` if you need comma separated numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array the action should be like this

```
export const getValue = (value) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_VALUE',
      payload: value.split(' ')
    });
  };
};
```