# React how click to input value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

it's possible to click input values in react?

so i have a input whihc i set values to array with comma:

it's here showing how i do that: 
[React / Redux how split input values with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478084/react-redux-how-split-input-values-with-comma?noredirect=1#comment101428311_57478084)

i can render my input values in jsx like that:

```
const listItems = this.props.Data.codes.map((item) =>
  <span key={index} onClick={onClick=event = () => this.somFunc(event, item)}>{item}</span>
);
```

and at onClick i can get the each item so each value which i put to array from input.

but possible to make this mapping in input ?

so in input will be displaying my values like:

```
value1 value2 value3
```

and i will be available to click them and call some function at `onClick`

Comment: Do you mean you want to have some sort of tag field? Look at this package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-input

Comment: Create an input field which shows data from the state.
Then, in ```somFunc(event, item)```, update the appropriate state value.

Comment: I already can show them in another place and click them it's okey but i want to make like that: so input where you will write and show them in one place https://ibb.co/tKCR1ZG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a tag input, you can use an existing package like this one. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-input

Or you can make your own control; follow this guide to do that:
https://medium.com/@jerrylowm/build-a-tags-input-react-component-from-scratch-1524f02acb9a

I will recommend using the npm package since it will have more community support.

Comment: yes i look the package but there is seems not putting tag into input

Comment: ou i understood the point there is just some css hack. Oke. thank you